# How to pull in null values when searching for specific document name

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am having issues pulling in null values in my query. I am looking for patients who have a specific document name in their chart but also want to show patients who do not have this specific document name as well. Right now my code is only pulling in the patients with the document name History and Physical (Transcription) but I need to see Null values as well. Below is my code:

[snip of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9JAW.png)

```
SELECT     CV3ClientVisit.ClientDisplayName, CV3ClientVisit.CurrentLocation, CV3ClientVisit.IDCode, CV3ClientVisit.VisitIDCode, CV3ClientVisit.VisitStatus, CV3ClientVisit.TypeCode, CV3ClientDocumentCUR.DocumentName
FROM        CV3ClientVisit INNER JOIN
                  CV3ClientDocumentCUR ON CV3ClientVisit.GUID = CV3ClientDocumentCUR.ClientVisitGUID
WHERE     (CV3ClientVisit.VisitStatus = 'ADM') AND (CV3ClientVisit.TypeCode = 'INPATIENT ADMIT') AND (CV3ClientDocumentCUR.DocumentName = 'History & Physical (transcription)' OR CV3ClientDocumentCUR.DocumentName IS NULL )
```

Comment: use `left join` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT cv.ClientDisplayName, cv.CurrentLocation, cv.IDCode, 
       cv.VisitIDCode, cv.VisitStatus, cv.TypeCode, cd.DocumentName
FROM CV3ClientVisit cv LEFT JOIN
     CV3ClientDocumentCUR cd
     ON cv.GUID = cd.ClientVisitGUID AND
        cd.DocumentName = 'History & Physical (transcription)'
WHERE cv.VisitStatus = 'ADM' AND
      cv.TypeCode = 'INPATIENT ADMIT' ;
```

I also added table aliases to simplify the query.